# How to recycle bitmap from android Gallery::GetView method

Tags: android, garbage-collection, gallery

In  getView method of gallery ,
i had download the bitmap and set to Imageview and return it back to framework. 
When and where should i recycle the bitmap ? 
I don't want to wake up the system garbage collector to clean up the bitmaps.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 
        downloadFromWeb("www.blahblah.com", i);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(mDisplayWidth, (mDisplayHeight-100)));
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return i;
    }

public downloadFromWeb(URL url, ImageView i){
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromWeb(url);
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
```

Comment: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, vote it and accepts the good answers of your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You can call bitmap recycle method in onDestory method as shown below

Bitmap mybitmap= null;

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(bm!=null)
        mybitmap.recycle();

    }
```

Comment: that works if you are holding a reference to the bitmap. what about when you hand it off to the view ? does it do this on its own ? or do i have to maintain a grip on the bitmaps I put in a gallery and make sure to release them when the gallery is done.